# getMapAsync in MapFragment can not be applied to java.lang.Runnable

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-mapview

I m trying to get map inside AsyncTask getting mentioned error at `this` in line `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` inside a fragment

```
private class BackGroundTaskForUserProfile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(getContext());
```

Comment: I think you are using Fragment. So, pleasevote up if your problem resolved.

Comment: yes I m using fragment but mainClass.this solved the problem